# How to display window titles on non-maximized windows in Unity 7.4?

Tags: window, unity, window-title

I recently moved from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS with all the resulting software upgrades. There have been a number of UI changes, but this one is most annoying.

Windows that are not maximized do not show the window name/title anywhere.
The menu bar does not evens display the application name; it's just "Text Editor" for gedit or "Files" for nautilus.
The title bar just sits empty.

This is very inconvenient for many reasons; for instance, if you have multiple (untabbed) instances of gedit open it's hard to tell which file is open where.
Titles *are* shown for the currently selected window in the application switcher, but that's little consolation.

How can I get window titles back to *title* bars?

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Unity 7.4.0.

<sub>I [posted this on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795074/how-to-display-window-titles-on-not-maximized-windows) but got no helpful reply.</sub>

Comment: Huh, the behaviour is funny for gedit: the title *does* show after saving the current file and vanishes again when I make changes.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to enable the Text plugin through CompizConfig Settings Manager.  I had the same trouble in Unity 14.04, and enabling that plugin fixed it.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1384843

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just now got around to checking back. Where do I find this Text plugin?

Comment: You can see here http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Switcher#Text for info on other Application Switcher/Ring Switcher/Shift Switcher parameters.

Comment: CompizConfig -> Image Loading -> Text

Comment: There's only PNG. Do I have to install some package?

Comment: I haven't installed anything to change my options in that dialog (that I know of). So that you know, the options I see are JPEG, PNG, SVG, Text , in that order.

Comment: Maybe not surprisingly, since it is a Compiz setting , it seems to work at any other desktop environment which supports Compiz, not just Unity.